# Illegal Nesting in HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

When I have this HAML file (Rails Layout)

```
!!! 5
%html
  %head
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'admin'
  %body
    %h1 ADMIN TEST
      = yield
```

I get the following error when I try to look at the page:

```
Illegal nesting: content can't be both given on the same line as %h1 and nested within it.
```

What gives?  (The error is pointed at the `yield` line).

Answer (score 1):

I see what I did.   The `= yield` is tabbed over as if it's inside the `%h1`, instead of being after it in the body. I overlooked that.